# Relating two foreign key columns in Table A to a primary key column in Table B

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem that's been on my neck for days. I've also searched the net to no avail...maybe I've been using the wrong search topic as a newbie.

I have two tables and their respective columns thus:

```
Table A: A_Id (int, PK); user1 (int); user2 (int)
Table B: B_Id (int, PK); name (nvarchar)
```

User1 & user2 are foreign keys to B_Id. My task is to write a SQL `select` statement that will display the table below:

```
Column Headings:      A_Id  User1   User2
Row records1:          1    Adam    Joe
Row records2:          2    John    Peter
```

I want to apply this to a messaging database I'm trying to create with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Is this possible? Or what better way I can achieve this?

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oops, so sorry for the clustered text. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join `A` with `B` twice:

```
SELECT a_id, b1.name AS user1, b2.name AS user2
FROM   a
JOIN   b AS b1 ON a.user1 = b.b_id
JOIN   b AS b2 ON a.user2 = b.b_id
```

Comment: thanks Mureinik. I'll apply your code and give you prompt feedback.

Comment: i keep getting the error "invalid column name 'name". Please advise.

Comment: Should probably be an explicit INNER JOIN.  If your database is case-sensitive, you may need to edit the answer to be "A_Id", and ensure all the column references are correct case.

Comment: Good work guys. I used INNER JOIN on mureinik's code as pmbAustin suggested, and it runs successfully. However, I still get that error message above. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Below Query will help you

```
SElect A_ID ,B.name,c.name
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.user1 = B.B_Id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON A.user2 = C.B_Id
```

Comment: Thanks Pragnesh. I'll reply you ASAP once i test your code.

Comment: Please see my above comment. your code seems right, but i don't know what I'm doing wrong.